# push notifications do NOT shown to the subscribers (web-push-php)

Tags: php, push-notification

I'm using web-push-php library for my project. The user can register/un-register for web notification but the message does NOT push to the specific user. following are my codes
main.js

```
'use strict';
const applicationServerPublicKey =  ew.vars.PubKey;
const pushButton = document.querySelector('.pushBTN');
let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;
function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');
  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}
//CODE HERE
//1
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
    swRegistration = swReg;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}
//2
function initializeUI() {
pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pushButton.disabled = true;
  if (isSubscribed) {
    unsubscribeUser();
  } else {
    subscribeUser();
  }
  });
  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
    if (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('User IS subscribed.');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
    }
    updateBtn();
  });
}
//3
function updateBtn() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }
  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-bell-slash text-danger"></i>';
  } else {
    pushButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-bell text-success"></i>';
  }
  pushButton.disabled = false;
}
//4
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
.then(function(swReg) {
  console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
  swRegistration = swReg;
  initializeUI();
})
//5
function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
    isSubscribed = true;
    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}
//6
const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
  userVisibleOnly: true,
  applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
})
//7
swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
  userVisibleOnly: true,
  applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
})
.then(function(subscription) {
  console.log('User is subscribed.');
  updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);
  isSubscribed = true;
  updateBtn();
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
  updateBtn();
});
//8
function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server
  if (subscription) {
    const key = subscription.getKey('p256dh');
    const token = subscription.getKey('auth');
    fetch('webpushregister.php', {
        method: 'post',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
        endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
        key: key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('p256dh')))) : null,
        token: token ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('auth')))) : null,
        axn: 'subscribe'
      })
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Error :(
        console.log('error');
    });
  } else {
    //subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
}
//9
function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      //updating database
      const key = subscription.getKey('p256dh');
      const token = subscription.getKey('auth');
      fetch('webpushregister.php', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
            key: key ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('p256dh')))) : null,
            token: token ? btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('auth')))) : null,
            axn: 'unsubscribe'
        })
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        // Error :(
        console.log('error removing from db');
        throw new error('error removing from db');
      });
      //end updating database     
      return subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
    isSubscribed = false;
    updateBtn();
  });
}
//10
swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
.then(function(subscription) {
  if (subscription) {
    // TODO: Tell application server to delete subscription
    return subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
})
```

my sw.js

```
'use strict';
//1
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
  const title = 'Push Codelab';
  const options = {
    body: 'Yay it works.4444444444',
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    badge: 'images/badge.png'
  };
const notificationPromise = self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
event.waitUntil(notificationPromise);
});
//2
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('https://developers.google.com/web/')
  );
});

//installing web application
self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(preLoad());
});
var preLoad = function(){
  console.log("Installing web app");
  return caches.open("offline").then(function(cache) {
    console.log("caching index and important routes");
    return cache.addAll(["/", "/offline.html"]);
  });
};
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  event.respondWith(checkResponse(event.request).catch(function() {
    return returnFromCache(event.request);
  }));
  event.waitUntil(addToCache(event.request));
});
var checkResponse = function(request){
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    fetch(request).then(function(response){
      if(response.status !== 404) {
        fulfill(response);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }, reject);
  });
};
var addToCache = function(request){
  return caches.open("offline").then(function (cache) {
    return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.url + " was cached");
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  });
};
var returnFromCache = function(request){
  return caches.open("offline").then(function (cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
     if(!matching || matching.status == 404) {
       return cache.match("offline.html");
     } else {
       return matching;
     }
    });
  });
};
```

and my php file

```
<?php
$siteconf = new SiteConfig();
use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;
$subscriber = ExecuteRow("SELECT * FROM subscribers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example/',
        'publicKey' => $siteconf->PublicKey, // don't forget that your public key also lives in app.js
        'privateKey' => $siteconf->PrivateKey, // in the real world, this would be in a secret file
    ),
);
// array of notifications
$notifications = [
    [
        'subscription' => Subscription::create([
            'endpoint' => $subscriber['endpoint'],
            'publicKey' => $siteconf->PublicKey,
            'authToken' => $subscriber['auth'],
        ]),
        'payload' => 'hello !',
    ], 
];
$webPush = new WebPush($auth);
// send multiple notifications with payload
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $webPush->sendNotification(
        $notification['subscription'],
        $notification['payload'] // optional (defaults null)
    );
}
/**
 * Check sent results
 * @var MessageSentReport $report
 */
foreach ($webPush->flush() as $report) {
    $endpoint = $report->getRequest()->getUri()->__toString();
    if ($report->isSuccess()) {
        echo "[v] Message sent successfully for subscription {$endpoint}.";
    } else {
        echo "[x] Message failed to sent for subscription {$endpoint}: {$report->getReason()}";
    }
}
/**
 * send one notification and flush directly
 * @var \Generator<MessageSentReport> $sent
 */
$sent = $webPush->sendNotification(
    $notifications[0]['subscription'],
    $notifications[0]['payload'], // optional (defaults null)
    true // optional (defaults false)
);
?>
```

I'm trying to send message to the last user in our database. I receive success message but the push message does NOT deliver.
What's the reason? how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following:

```
'contentEncoding' => $message["contentEncoding"]
```

It should be placed under the comment // array of notifications.

I am having an issue regarding this but it's the opposite of yours. I am only able to send a notification for the very last row but not the other rows.